# Tmux ranger integration: opening text files in new panes

Tags: linux, vim, tmux, nano

Here we have some amazing tools: tmux, ranger, vim... Would be amazing to configure ranger to open the files (when text editable) in a tmux newpane? Is that easy and how it is done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of 2022, Python 2 is no longer supported. Here is what works for me on ranger 1.9.3 on macOS via Homebrew.

```
map ef shell [[ -n $TMUX ]] && tmux split-window -h vim %f
```

or

```
map ef eval exec('try: from shlex import quote\nexcept ImportError: from pipes import quote\nif "TMUX" in os.environ: fm.run("tmux splitw -h vim " + quote(fm.thisfile.basename))')
```

It is based on [the official ranger wiki](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Keybindings#open-highlighted-files-in-splits-windows) with minor tweaks:

- For some reason, I don't have the `rifle` command, so I use `vim` instead.
- Added checking for $TMUX env, so only open a new tmux pane if ranger is under a tmux session already, as requested in the comment thread.

Note the first way depends on bash (need to tweak `[[` part if other shells), and the second way depends on Python shlex or pipes module.

### Historical Info Below

To open the current selected file in ranger in a new pane (to the right) in an ad-hoc manner, you can first go to ranger's command line (by pressing :) and then type `shell tmux splitw -h vim %f` following by the `<Enter>` key.

Note: these methods below do not work with filenames with space characters!

To achieve this with some key binding, you can set it in a configuration file of ranger. For ranger 1.6+, key bindings are specified in `rc.conf`. So in `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf`, use something like this:

```
map ef eval if 'TMUX' in os.environ.keys(): fm.execute_console("shell tmux splitw -h 'vim " + fm.thisfile.basename + "'")
```

While with ranger 1.4 you need a file `~/.config/ranger/keys.py` with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Customized key bindings.

from ranger.api.keys import *

map = keymanager.get_context('browser')
@map("ef")
def edit_file_in_new_tmux_pane(arg):
    command = "shell tmux splitw -h 'vim " + arg.fm.env.cf.basename + "'"
    if 'TMUX' in os.environ.keys(): arg.fm.execute_console(command)
```

With the above setting when you press `ef` in the ranger's browser, it will open a new tmux pane with vim editing the selected file.

The code is simply for demo, and it might need to involve with more safeguarding, such as checking for file type, etc.

Credit goes to ranger's help manual and `$(pythonpkginstalldir)/ranger/defaults/rc.conf` (`$(pythonpkginstalldir)/ranger/defaults/keys.py` for ranger 1.4). They are really helpful.

Comment: From `tmux` typing `:shell tmux splitw -h 'vim %f'<Enter>` worked ok for me, but `$ TMPFILE=\`mktemp\`; strace ranger 2> $TMPFILE; grep keys $TMPFILE; rm $TMPFILE` hinted no `keys.py` access. For a minimum context can tell `$ tmux -V` vomited `tmux 1.6` and `uname -a` vomited `Linux ????????? 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: @uprego Oh ranger 1.6 does not use keys.py anymore. It uses rc.conf instead for keybindings etc. Sorry for the delay since I just updated my ranger lately and recognized this :( I'll put an update soon.

Comment: I'm seeing it working now, and it's good. However I'm not sure this could be a complete _use case_ yet, because I would want that this could be done only from `ranger`s checking that they are inside the scope of a tmux session (what surely can be worked around with different approaches) to not affect an unrelated tmux session (happened). Just a minor point: I'm currently using `ranger-master 1.6.1` and `ranger 1.5.4 (stable)` in two hosts at hand reach, and both fetch rc.conf and none keys.py.

Comment: I just find tmux will set the environment variable `$TMUX` inside its session, so checking it should be enough. Try this: `map ef eval if os.environ.has_key('TMUX'): fm.execute_console("shell tmux splitw -h 'vim " + fm.thisfile.basename + "'")`

Comment: It seems that if the Python is version 3, `os.environ` doesn't have `has_key` method. Instead, one could use `eval if 'TMUX' in os.environ.keys()`

Comment: @Jason seems Python 2 also has `os.environ.keys()` so I've updated the answer with the more compatible way. Thanks!

Comment: The answer still works , Ranger 1.9.3, tmux 3.1c. But **not** for *file names with spaces*. Any ideas how to work with them also?

Comment: @Krackout, I updated the answer to use `quote()` to work with file names with spaces.

Comment: @alick, works perfectly, thank you!